# cannot access one class from another class in java

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I am writing a java application that use SQLite as database. I am trying to use a separate class file for the database connection and use it in other classes for DB connection.

```
private void insertActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    //Statement statement= null;
   // PreparedStatement ps = null;
    //Connection con = null;

    try {
    Connect_db con = new Connect_db();
    //con = conn.getConnection();
    String query = "insert into emp_info (emp_id,emp_pwd,emp_name,emp_addres,emp_salary) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
    Connection conn = con.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(emp_id.getText()));
    ps.setString(2, emp_pwd.getText());
    ps.setString(3, emp_name.getText());
    ps.setString(4, emp_addres.getText());
    ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(emp_salary.getText()));
    ps.executeUpdate(query);
    ps.close();
    conn.close();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(admin_emp_insert.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

This is calling class of the connection class.

```
public class Connect_db {        
public Connection getConnection()
{
    Connection con=null;
    try
    {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Hasan/Desktop/SQLiteStudio/central.db";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;        
}}
```

This is the connection class for making connection with the SQLite.
But after compiling the calling class it give me an error.

```
C:\Users\Hasan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaProject\src\javaproject\admin_emp_insert.java:181: error: cannot access Connect_db
    Connect_db con = new Connect_db();
bad source file: C:\Users\Hasan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaProject\src\javaproject\Connect_db.java
file does not contain class javaproject.Connect_db
```

But both class is in the same folder. I tried my best but couldn't solve it. If you think it is a duplicate question please mark it as duplicate. And as it is my first post some mistake can be there.

Comment: Have you put them in the same package?

Comment: Yes, i have put them in the same package.

Comment: And what's that package's name?

Comment: Very probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831183/java-error-bad-source-file-file-does-not-contain-class-x-please-remove-or-m

Comment: Or to ask this a different way, what is the `package` directive for each class?

Comment: both class are in `package javaproject;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `Connect_db` class, at the top inside the class where your `insertActionPerformed` function is contained.

```
import Connect_db; // If it's in the same package

public class X {
     private void insertActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                       
     /* implementation */        
     }

     /* Further class details */
}
```

Comment: They said that "both class [sic] is in the same folder", meaning the same package, meaning no, there is not a need for an `import`.

Comment: @LewBloch. Now we know that, not then.

Comment: Yep...well it's in the comments now.

Comment: thanks for the help. i just used clean and build and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

i think its about chmod.

error: cannot access Connect_db.