# my code doesn't work (java) using if statement and error if i convert string to interger

Tags: java, if-statement

```
  import java.util.*;
    public class DateC { //class
    public static void main(String[] args) { //main
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner
    String date,non1,non2,non3; //declatation
    int rar1,rar2,rar3;
    int conv1,conv2,conv3;
    int day,mnth,year,day2=0;
    int mnth2=0;
    int year2=0;

System.out.println("Please enter three integers representing a date as: mm nn yyyy"); //to get data from user
date =read.nextLine(); 
rar1=date.indexOf(' '); //to cut first two number
non1=date.substring(0,rar1); // it's the first two number 
rar2=date.indexOf(' ',rar1+1); // to cut the month number
non2=date.substring(rar1+1,rar2); //month
rar3=date.indexOf(' ',rar2+1); // to cut the year
non3=date.substring(rar2+1,(date.length())); //year
day =Integer.parseInt(non1); //convert string to Integer
mnth=Integer.parseInt(non2); //string to integer
year=Integer.parseInt(non3); //string to integer
```

the error is in last three lines
it's said

---

> DateC.java:19: error: cannot access Integer day
>   =Integer.parseInt(non1); //convert string to Integer ^

bad source file: .\Integer.java file does not contain class Integer

---

Comment: More code please

Comment: please update your question with complete code so that OP can help you

Comment: We don't need all your code, we need a [mcve], i.e. *enough* code to reproduce your issue, but no more.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831183/java-error-bad-source-file-file-does-not-contain-class-x-please-remove-or-m).

Comment: and now? i edit

Answer (score 0):

All these lines

```
date =read.nextLine(); 
rar1=date.indexOf(' '); //to cut first two number
non1=date.substring(0,rar1); // it's the first two number 
rar2=date.indexOf(' ',rar1+1); // to cut the month number
non2=date.substring(rar1+1,rar2); //month
rar3=date.indexOf(' ',rar2+1); // to cut the year
non3=date.substring(rar2+1,(date.length())); //year
day =Integer.parseInt(non1); //convert string to Integer
mnth=Integer.parseInt(non2); //string to integer
year=Integer.parseInt(non3); //string to integer
```

can be changed to.

```
day = read.nextInt();
mnth = day = read.nextInt();
year = day = read.nextInt();
```

Comment: thanks but it's not allowed to write a program with a few lines , i want know where's the mistake