# type Map does not take parameters

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to write a simple program for adding key value pairs in hash map and traverse them.
The code is :-

```
import java.util.*;
public class MapExample{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
         map.put(1,"Palla");
         map.put(2,"Durga");
         map.put(3,"Deepak");
         for(Map.Entry entry:map.entrySet())
            System.out.println("key is "+entry.getKey()+" "+"value is "+entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

When I am compiling this program it will throw this error:-

```
MapExample.java:7: error: type Map does not take parameters
       Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
          ^
```

I solved it by modifying

```
import java.util.*;
```

as

```
import java.util.Map;
```

now this error is gone ,but it is again throwing the following error:-

```
MapExample.java:7: error: cannot access HashMap
       Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
                                   ^
  bad source file: .\HashMap.java
    file does not contain class HashMap
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

I understood the error and i added

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Now the complete program is working fine , what I am feeling ambigious is that
why it is not working fine with

```
import java.util.*;
```

unless we need to declare the import statements Map and HashMap explicitly.

fixes:

```
 MapExample.java:7: error: cannot access HashMap
           Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
                                       ^
      bad source file: .\HashMap.java
        file does not contain class HashMap
        Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

this error got fixed after deleting `HashMap.java` which is in my current working directory.
But  this error

```
 MapExample.java:7: error: type Map does not take parameters
           Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
              ^
```

remains same.

The above error has also got fixed by deleting `Map.java`in current working directory.All errors got fixed.

Comment: can you add your package structure? and how are you compiling the class?

looks like a class path issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831183/java-error-bad-source-file-file-does-not-contain-class-x-please-remove-or-m

Comment: bad source file: ".\HashMap.java" - do you have a source file in the working dir, named HashMap.java? The compiler would normally take compiled classes out of a jar, not source files.

Comment: What tool/IDE are you using to edit/compile your program?

Comment: I am using Sublime editor for writing and compiling in cmd. Jim Garrison

Comment: I am not using any package , i am simply compiling that java program    @enator.

Comment: @userunknown .. I got it , there is a file named HashMap.java in my cwd, after deleting that HashMap.java that error was gone, but the error :type Map does not take parameters is not fixed

Comment: Is there any Map.java as well in your directory?

and by package structure I meant, paste content of your tree directory.

Comment: @enator ..got it ,there is also another file Map.java ,i deleted it and it is working fine,