# Cannot access my created separate class getting cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, class, package

I am sure this is a pretty simple problem I am having but I am trying to access a class from a separate file in the package I am working on and when I try to compile I am getting the error cannot find symbol List stocks = new ArrayList(); I have not had to pull a class from a separate file before. when I try to compile the entire package using imassars_a1/*.java I am getting an error saying permission denied to the ePortfolio.java

the ePortfolio code:
package imassars_a1;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ePortfolio{
public static void main (String[] args){
List<stock> stocks = new ArrayList<stock>();
//List<mutualFund> mutualfunds = new ArrayList<mutualFund>(); 
Scanner menu=new Scanner(System.in);
int menuItem;
Scanner investchoice=new Scanner(System.in);
int investChoice;
String delimiters = " ";
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Double price;
int quant;
Scanner prices=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a Number between 1 and 5");
System.out.println("(1) Buy");
System.out.println("(2) Sell");
System.out.println("(3) Update");
System.out.println("(4) get Gain");
System.out.println("(5) End Program.");
menuItem=menu.nextInt( );
while (menuItem>=1&&menuItem<=5){
    if(menuItem==1){
        System.out.println("(1) Stock");
        System.out.println("(2) Mutual Fund");
        investChoice=investchoice.nextInt( );
        if(investChoice==1){
        System.out.println("Enter the Stock name followed by space and then Symbol");
        String entry= keyboard.nextLine( );
        while(entry.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Please try again");
            entry= keyboard.nextLine( );
            } 
        StringTokenizer stockChoice = new StringTokenizer(entry, delimiters);
        String name = stockChoice.nextToken( );
        String symbol=stockChoice.nextToken( );
        System.out.println("Enter your price");
        price=prices.nextDouble( );
        System.out.println("Enter your quantity");
        quant=prices.nextInt( );
        stock StocksOne = new stock (name,symbol,quant,price,0.0);    
        stocks.add(StocksOne);
        }

    }



menuItem=menu.nextInt( );    
}



}
}
```

The stock class code:

```
 package imassars_a1;

 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;


public class stock{

public static final double Commission = 9.99;
private String Symbol;
private String Name;
private int Quantity;
private Double Price;
private Double bookValue=0.0;

public stock(String Symbol, String Name, int Quantity,Double Price,Double bookValue) {
    this.Symbol = Symbol;
    this.Name=Name;
    this.Quantity=Quantity;
    this.Price=Price;
    this.bookValue=bookValue;
  }  
  public double getPrice() {
    return Price;
  }
  public String getSymbol() {
    return Symbol;
 }
 public String getName() {
    return Name;
 }      
 public int getQuantity() {
    return Quantity;
 } 
 public double getbookValue() {
    return bookValue;
 }
 public double computebookValue(int quantity, double price) {
    bookValue=(quantity*price)+Commission;   
    return bookValue;
}

public double calcbookValue() {
    return computebookValue(Quantity, Price);
}
```

}

Comment: your code compiles with no errors for me, maybe there's something corrupt with the file in the OS on disk, in memory, or has altered permissions -- Try making a backup copy of file `ePortfolio.java` and recreating an empty file, copy the contents from that backup file into the new file and save it as `ePortfolio.java`, and try compile again?

Comment: thank you so much should I just cope and paste into a blank?

Comment: post your results back here and if still problems we can troubleshoot further

Comment: zsh: permission denied: imassars_a1/ePortfolio.java still coming up, I deleted the previous file and created a new one ane save that

Comment: if I compile javac ePortfolio.java I am getting the same errors of symbol stock not found

Comment: if I capitalize Package i only got 1 error

Comment: Which Operating system are you using? looks like Mac or Linux ?

Comment: what's the full path of the `imassars_a1` directory the java files are in? are you in a normal user directory? not in a system directory like `/home/root/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin`

Comment: I am using mac, when I remade the files I got this error, ePortfolio.java:9: error: cannot access stock
    List<stock> stocks = new ArrayList<stock>();
         ^
  bad source file: ./stock.java
    file does not contain class stock
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the source path.
1 error

Comment: the full path is: Documents/CIS2430/imassars_a1/imassars_a1

Comment: are both files `ePortfolio.java` , `stock.java` in the same folder: `Documents/CIS2430/imassars_a1/imassars_a1`?

Comment: they are I am trying to remake the folder too

Comment: there may be an issue with the two sub-folders being the same name, that might confuse with the package name...

Comment: I was comparing your errors to [Java error - bad source file: file does not contain class x . Please remove or make sure it appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831183/java-error-bad-source-file-file-does-not-contain-class-x-please-remove-or-m)

Comment: try moving the `java` files up one level to : `Documents/CIS2430/imassars_a1/` and delete the extra sub-folder `imassars_a1/`, and try to compile again from `Documents/CIS2430/`

Comment: I got it to compile when I backed out of the folder in terminal and used javac imassars_a1/*.java I am not sure how to run it now to check

Comment: run it the same as you did before, but go up one directory to `Documents/CIS2430/` and run `java imassars_a1.ePortfolio`

Comment: got it thank you soo much youre a lifesaver

Comment: great! glad you got it working!